# literature on small samples and parametric survival models

Tags: references, survival, small-sample, censoring, misspecification

I have an abundance of small data sets with right-censored data. There are different groups in each data set and I'd like to get confidence intervals for the regression parameters. Each data set has 3-6 replicates per group and the percent censoring is usually small (say 5%) but not always.

I can't see to find much in the literature except this paper [1] which is more focused on misspecification than I need (and I don't really care about the Cox model in this instance).

For example, most references use Z values to compute the intervals. My intuition is to substitute a t percentile but the df are somewhat subjective (do I include scale parameters when I count?).

I'm doing to limited simulations and finding decent power but somewhat inflated alpha values.

[1] Li, Y.-H., Klein, J. P., & Moeschberger, M. L. (1996). Effects of model misspecification in estimating covariate effects in survival analysis for small sample sizes. Computational Statistics and Data Analysis, 22(2), 177–192. doi:10.1016/0167-9473(96)88029-7